# how to replace content of specified column in a huge file using Unix Command

Tags: unix, file-io, sed

I have a huge file around 10 GB. And I want to replace its 35th column (separated by ;). Since, its a huge file, opening file in an editor is not an option. I want to do replace in all the lines of file.

Somebody suggested me to use Sed but i am not comfortable with it yet. Could somebody suggest a unix command that can achieve the same.

Comment: You can do it with awk or perl. They can't edit the file in place, they'll create a new file with the modified contents.

Comment: "Without opening" isn't right; you open it and read and write a line at a time instead of reading in the entire file at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F';' '{ $35 = "replacement" }' < oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -i 's/[^;]*/replacement/35' file
```

Answer (score 0):

the accepted solution didn't work for me. But helped me in finding this:

awk '{$35 = "replacement"; print $0}' < oldfile > newfile

for a tab separated file